# CSV File does not exist , Python, Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-science, opencsv

I've downloaded a csv, let's call it april.csv

Then I got an error message, april.csv does not exist.

I tried to open it like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\Lenovo\Downloads\pydata_pandas-master.zip\pydata_pandas-master\data\april.csv")
```

I also tried it without " ", I tried it with ', I also tried it with two backslashes, C:\Users etc.

Nothing worked.

Comment: add `r` before the path.

Comment: `'\'` is a special character for escaping special characters, you should use forward slashes `'/'` or pass a raw string by prepending with a `'r'`

Comment: do you see it in `os.listdir()`?

Comment: You are trying to read a file inside a zip file using Pandas which apparently won't work.

Comment: It worked with the forward slash. Thank you

Comment: worked with ziped path?

Answer (score 0):

Please first unzip file and try below approach from unzipped directory.

```
df=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\alice\\Downloads\\emp.csv",encoding='latin-1')
```